# Robot Framework parallel command execution

Tags: linux, bash, robotframework

I have a testcase containing multiple *Execute Commands (SSH Library)* which are calling different commands in Linux environment. The main thing I would like to do is to run some of them in parallel. By default Robot performs one command and after it finishes, performs the next one.

As for me it is not a good behavior, I would like to have my command executed during execution of previous one. For example:

```
Execute Command    ./script.sh
Execute Command    ./script_parallel.sh
```

What I would like Robot to do:

- Execute script.sh
- During execution perform script_parallel.sh (which will finish before script.sh finishes)
- Finish script.sh

Comment: Call `script_parallel.sh &` from within `script.sh`.  The ampersand means fork the process.

Answer (score 0):

Will it be possible to use GNU Parallel?

```
Execute Command    parallel ::: ./script.sh ./script_parallel.sh
```

Comment: Well, of course it's a sort of solution, but I would really like to have a control when to execute second command. I don't want to run both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Start command](https://robotframework-sshlibrary.googlecode.com/git-history/1.1/doc/SSHLibrary.html#Start%20Command)? It starts the command in background and returns immediately. To verify successful execution of commands you need [Read Command Output](https://robotframework-sshlibrary.googlecode.com/git-history/1.1/doc/SSHLibrary.html#Read%20Command%20Output).